# Keras LSTM error - Logits and labels should have the same shape

Tags: python, keras, classification, lstm, keras-layer

I am trying to do a binary classification using Keras LSTM.

My input data is of shape 2340 records * 254 features.

The output is 1*2340.

Below is my code.

```
X_res = np.array(X_res)
X_res =  np.reshape(X_res,([1,2340,254]))
y_res = np.array(y_res)
y_res = np.reshape(y_res,([1,2340]))
y_test = np.array(y_test)
y_test = np.reshape(y_test,([1,314]))

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32 ,input_dim = 254,return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
model.fit(X_res, y_res, epochs= 5)
```

However I am unable to go past the error:

**ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 2340))**

Comment: your output layer must be Dense(2340, ...)

Comment: Thanks  that worked !but the shape of my predicted Y is (1,2340) which is same as Y_train. How do I get it to be the correct shape as per my X_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the last layer to match the desired output shape (from 1 to 2340). By running the example code below you see how it work in practice:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

#let's simulate...
X_res=np.random.rand(2340,254)
y_res=np.random.rand(1,2340)
y_test=np.random.rand(1,314)

X_res = np.array(X_res)
X_res =  np.reshape(X_res,([1,2340,254]))
y_res = np.array(y_res)
y_res = np.reshape(y_res,([1,2340]))
y_test = np.array(y_test)
y_test = np.reshape(y_test,([1,314]))

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32 ,input_dim = 254,return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2340, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model.summary()

#test a littlebit before training...
test_input=tf.ones((1,2340,254))

print("Test result of original model: ",model(test_input).numpy())

#train...
model.fit(X_res, y_res, epochs= 5)

#test after training...just to show the shapes of inputs and outputs. Change the number of inputs you want to test to see the effect...

how_many_inputs_you_want_to_test=1
X_test=np.random.rand(how_many_inputs_you_want_to_test,2340,254)
print("Input shape: ", X_test.shape)
y_pred = (model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")
print("Output shape: ",y_pred.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have one additional questin though. When I try to predict using the model , the shape of y_pred is (1,2340) instead of (1,314). I am using below statement.       
                                                                                                                                       X_test = np.array(X_test)       ,       
X_test =  np.reshape(X_test,([1,314,254]))       ,                                                                                          y_pred = (model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")

Comment: Take care the shape of the input is correct. I added short "test after training" part to the original answer including the code, in this example you can see there the correct shape format, and see also how increase of test cases increase corresponding size of the output.

Comment: If my test data is 314 records * 254 features , how is it possible for me to reshape it into ( 314 * 2340 * 254) ??

Comment: It is not possible, I'll add another answer which gives an example of the reshaping in your case. Please note in reshaping tensors the sizes of the tensor before and tensor after reshape need to be appropriate. In conversions follow the logic; "if I have a puzzle of 2x2 pieces, it is possible to reshape it to "1x4" pieces puzzle or "4x1" pieces of puzzle but e.g. not to puzzle of size "3x2" because the number of pieces is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Advice how to reshape tensors in this question case:

```
#About tensors and reshaping
import tensorflow as tf

#The tensor need to be reshaped:
example_tensor=tf.ones((314,254))

try:
    #The reshaping is done by the command:
    example_tensor_reshaped=tf.reshape(example_tensor,[314,2340,254])
except:
    print("Sorry, this conversion is not possible!")
#----> which produce an error!

#Why? Because the reshaping is possible only with compatible sizes, for example conversion:
print("...thus let's try again with a different conversion...")
#The tensor need to be reshaped:
example_tensor=tf.ones((314,254*2340))

#The reshaping is done by the command:
example_tensor_reshaped=tf.reshape(example_tensor,[314,2340,254])

#----> which happens succesfully!
print("The shape of reshaped tensor: ",example_tensor_reshaped.shape)
```